# Private and public APIs on AWS Lambda Serverless

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am working on a serverless project (Node JS) and it has multiple lambda API. Some APIs are going to be used by internal network and some by external network.

I want to make those external APIs private but at the same time want to keep internal APIs public. **So basically there will be some public and some private lambda APIs in the same serverless project**.

I have tried using VPC but it's not working. As soon as I implemented VPC, it made all the APIs private.

Can someone help me with the proper solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is "lambda API"...is that lambda with API Gateway, or invoking lambda directly?

Comment: @LostJon - yes, its a lambda API with API gateway

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you need multiple API Gateways:

1. Public

- can be reached from anywhere - ie 0.0.0.0/0

2. Private

- can only be hit from allowed VPC

This is a configuration when you initialize your API Gateway (ie "Endpoint Type"). Check out [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html) for more info! I promise it feels like overhead initially, but you have done 2 beautiful things:

1. Made your Infrastructure more secure
2. Isolated your code (one step closer to microservices).